# GMSMapView hiding navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, cgrect, google-maps-sdk-ios

I implemented the GMSMapView via the Googla Maps iOS SDK

the example code from Google suggests to declare the view more or less just dropping this method in your code

```
- (void)loadView {
    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                            longitude:151.20
                                                                 zoom:6];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.view = mapView_;

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
    marker.title = @"Sydney";
    marker.snippet = @"Australia";
    marker.map = mapView_;
}
```

it automagically works, but the mapView happens to cover my navigationItem
it's clear that the maps take its dimension at the initWithFram:CGRectZero
but simply changing the parameter to a custom CGRect

```
CGRect square = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
```

haven't worked for me, any other suggestion?
i only need to display the map between the Nav Item and the Tab Bar (but the second doesn't happen to be covered)

[image: Google maps covering nav bar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the mapView_ was being set as the whole view

```
self.view = mapView_;
```

calculating the correct dimension and adding it as a subview was the correct way to solve it

```
CGRect f = self.view.frame;
CGRect mapFrame = CGRectMake(f.origin.x, 44, f.size.width, f.size.height);
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:mapFrame camera:camera];
[self.view addSubview:mapView_];
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped with the Swift version. I wonder, though, if that is the correct way to do it, i.e., relying on the size of the navigation bar (44) to offset the mapview.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your view controller for the map is part of a navigation stack of a `UINavigationController`. I had no problems pushing a `UITabBarController` with a map and a list tab onto a view controller embedded in a `UINavigationController`. This way the navigationbar view belongs only to the `UINavigationController` and the map controller view shouldn't cover it.

Comment: you made a point, i have a simple UIViewController with a NavigationItem on top, not a NavigationBar